# Unexpected interaction between microtype and \parindent

Tags: indentation, microtype

The `microtype` package (or more likely the pdfTeX microtypographic extensions) have a strange interaction with `\parindent` that bit me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
0:\vrule\strut\par
1:\vrule\strut\par
\parindent0pt
0:\vrule\strut\par
1:\vrule\strut\par
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
0:\vrule\strut\par
1:\vrule\strut\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

The colon after the second `1` is typeset slightly to the left of the one after the 0, but only when `microtype`'s protrusion is on and `\parindent` is 0. Indeed, changing the `\parindent` to .00001 pt causes the rules to line up.

This seems like a bug to me, but it's possible that I just don't understand what is supposed to happen here.

The two work arounds are to either disable protrusion where I need this to line up, or change the `\parindent` to a small, nonzero value. Is there a better option?

Comment: @lockstep: My question isn't really about indentation—which covers a wide variety of topics. It's specifically about the interaction between `microtype` and `\parindent`.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. If `\parindent` is set to 0, then `microtype` applies margin kerning, so that the `1` will slightly protrude into the left margin. Of course, it's debatable whether the same thing should not also happen when `\parindent` is said to 0.00001pt.

Comment: @TH.: Especially after @Michael's comment, I'd say that your question is about an interaction between `microtype` and indentation (or the lack of), and that {indentation} is a proper tag. Whether an extra {parindent} tag is needed is open to debate. Also note that concept tags are preferred to command tags.

Comment: @Michael: Seems odd that it wouldn't always perform the protrusion into the indentation box.

Comment: @lockstep: If you say so. I don't really care about tags, it just seemed odd.

Comment: @TH.: One more thing: If a "specific" {parindent} tag would be available in addition to the "general" {indentation} tag, many new users would use {parindent} even when {indentation} would be appropriate. That said, I'll keep this question in mind in case another specific {parindent} question crops up.

Comment: @lockstep: That is a good point and a good reason not to use it.

Comment: @Michael: You should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Michael Ummels: This is lockstep again. Please convert your comment into an answer -- doing so will decrease the number of unanswered questions by 1 and increase your reputation by at least 10. :-)

Comment: @lockstep: Sorry, I wanted to write an answer before, but I was very busy. Anyway, here you are. :-)

Comment: @Michael: Worth the wait. =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea behind the `protrusion` option in the `microtype` package is to allow certain characters protrude into the margin, which can help to make the margins look more even to the human eye. As Hàn Thế Thành puts it in his dissertation:

> Margin kerning is needed for optical
>   alignment of the margins of a typeset
>   text, because mechanical justification
>   of the margins makes them look rather
>   ragged. Some characters can make a
>   line appear shorter to the human eye
>   than others. Shifting such characters
>   by an appropriate amount into the
>   margins would greatly improve the
>   appearance of a typeset text.

The protrusion settings for certain fonts such as Computer Modern are contained in the file `mt-cmr.cfg` that comes with the `microtype` package. As you can see, the package author has decided that the glyph `1` should protrude into the left margin, while the glyph `0` should not, which explains the difference you can observe between the second example (protrusion activated) and the third one (protrusion disabled).

As to whether the first character of an indented paragraph should also protrude to the left, I am not sure. Usually, paragraphs are longer than one line, so the indented lines do not form a single margin. In any case, I think this behaviour is hardwired into pdfTeX, so one should ask the developers of pdfTeX if this is intended.

Comment: Excellent answer which doesn't just give a solution but explains it appropriately. Well done!